# filter ListView using RestApi in sharepoint APP

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, filter, jsom

Please let me know is there any way to filter list inside listview using restapi

Example: TestList
[image: Total item in list]

And below is my custom search:(currently it is configured on Title field)
[image]

Now after filter(**Title=*he***) using restapi, it should show only those data in which **Title** contains '**he**'

So Output will be:
[image: filtered result in list]

I know it is possible using **URL query string**. but I dont want to show filter value on url(like /TestList/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=*he*)

So I want to build it using REST or JSOM or JQuery etc(any client side language which can be used in APP)

Comment: Can you add more description?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use REST API to filter list view (for exemple your SPView: /TestList/AllItems.aspx)

To filter list view you should use CAML query (in the list settings, you could edit your views, and ADD filter to fields of your list). (ou can group, and do operation like count/sum/avarage ....). The user will not view this filter (so give to it a good title).
This is the best way to filter a view, and it's simple. You can do this simply by using the SharePoint UI (List Settings => Views => Clic on your view To edit it => see Filter section)
Or you can do this programmatically (by using the property [Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.query.aspx)) and Build your own SPQuery. (to build SPQuery there is a lot of doc/tuto on internet)

If this solution is not appropriate, you could use REST API yes. But you must create your own application page, Build a custom logic to render fields Data. And use REST API to get your data. Using REST API you can Filter data. But when you query the list you have to use GET protocol with specific parameter in URL. THis will help you to understand the logic to build filter with REST API : [query operations in SharePoint REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx)
But with this solution, you have to manage everything by hand (paginate query to avoid threshold list, the Quick edit, .....).

It depend on your need and if you have times.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. if i use SPQuery and update the view then, it is going to reflect for everyone.

Comment: It depend on your SPView (you can have public SPView (for every one) or personal SPView (only for you)) In general it's public SPView

Comment: It is very difficult to filter lists using SPView in App(same app for all lists).

Comment: Is there any other way without creating personal view and updating it.

Comment: You should able to create custom view when you create your list in your apps. When you create your custom list, you could create custom SPView in the schema.xml of your list template

Comment: okay but for that i have to change in list. but i dont want to change anything in list. It should be like i have list name and using that do whatever coding in separate APP and according to that filter that list by Title in the same listview

Comment: If I understand, you want to create a generic list view. You pass to it the title of the list. And your "generic view" display data of the list (title that you pass in param)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42310/discussion-between-nico-and-anil-pal).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can filter data of list using REST API ! check this link, a tutorial by Microsoft : [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx)

Comment: when I add this answer your post have no much details... So i will answer it with a little more text